# Different Optional/Option semantics in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, option-type, functional-java

I am trying to understand reasons behind different Option/Optional semantics in probably 3 most used implementations in Java ecosystem: Java 8, Functional Java and Guava.

Considering following three snippets.

1. `java.util.Optional.of(100).map(i -> null)` results in `Optional.empty`.
2. `fj.data.Option.some(100).map(i -> null)` results in `Some(null)`.
3. `com.google.common.base.Optional.of(100).transform(i -> null)` results `NullPointerException`.

What are the reasons behind 3 choices? If appicable, what can be considered most "pure" or "correct" from functional programming point of view? For example, in terms of viewing `Option` type as monad, what would be most correct; or what can be considered most composable? It would also interesting to know how this is handled in functional languages that allow nulls.

Comment: Different Objective of coding(optimise, secure or without crash) I think, you should read for example Java good practice book. For example avoid null when return list, you should return emptyList. Exception should remain as their name, Exceptions.

Comment: The same reason why C# and Java aren't exactly equal. Different developers with different opinions how "it" should work. Asking _us_ why _they_ thought so is quite strange.

Comment: @Tom slightly expanded the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a real reason for Guava's behavior. As for the other two, it depends how the author defined null values:

- java 8 defined `null` value to be the absence of value, thus you get an `Optional.empty`
- functional java seemed to have defined `null` as a possible value, distinct from no value.

  For a more concrete reason, lets take a look at [`map`](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Option.java#L194) definition:

  ```
  public final <B> Option<B> map(final F<A, B> f) {
     return isSome() ? some(f.f(some())) : Option.none();
  }
  ```

  As long as the 'container' is not `None`, its transformed value will not be `None`. To get a result similar to java 8, [`fromNull`](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Option.java#L677) could be used.

As for 'pure' or 'correct', probably a similar answer to the old [is 0 a natural number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/293/339674) :)